# Is there a way to determine the issue with the info.plist causing this crash?

Tags: xcode, apple-developer

When attempting to archive an application using Xcode 15, the progress gets to the `Signing ipa` portion then crashes with the below information.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [15710]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               15.0 (22265)
Build Info:            IDEApplication-22265000000000000~3 (15A240d)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-10-30 21:18:31.3872 -0400
OS Version:            macOS 13.6 (22G120)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        BEF69C9D-CF8D-5B49-999B-99E7E49C1E3B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FDEB6246-B8CE-4202-8970-1130064E877D

Time Awake Since Boot: 21000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       20425 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: archive info plist lock

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process:   Xcode [15710]

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
com.apple.main-thread
```

I am not sure what to try to be honest. I attempted to clean the derived data, clean the build folder, restart the computer, and restart Xcode all with no luck.

Comment: What Info.plist issue are you referring to? Have you tried the latest version of Xcode to see if the issue is fixed? Xcode 15.0.1 is out as it Xcode 15.1 beta 2.

Comment: I will try Xcode 15.0.1 anfd see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When implementing a version, I included a letter character `v2.0.1`. Upgrading from Xcode 15 to Xcode 15.0.1 and attempting to upload provided me with a much cleaner error response indicating this. After fixing this issue, I successfully was able to upload.

Comment: It's hard to believe that Xcode was crashing because your version number started with a letter. Shame on Apple.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 15.1** and **15.2**

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: archive info plist lock
```

When verifying or uploading an archive (using custom not Xcode build), Xcode would crash at the point of checking the version number.

What fixed it for me was to agree to the Apple Developer Licence at the developer account. Get an Admin to do it if you don't have privileges.

https://developer.apple.com/account